# Wget download queue script

Tags: php, wget

The idea is that when wget is running and downloading something, I can just add another URL that will be downloaded once the current download is finished. I only want to download 1 file at a time. I wrote this script

```
#!/bin/bash

test=/tmp/wget-download-link.txt

echo -n "$test" | while IFS= read -N 1 a; do

    wget -o /tmp/wget.log -P /mnt/usb -i /tmp/wget-download-link.txt

    if [[ "$a" == $'\n' ]] ; then
        wget -nc -o /tmp/wget.log -P /mnt/usb -i /tmp/wget-download-link.txt
    fi

    #printf "$a"
    echo download finished

done
```

The script will check for any new lines that consist of URLs, if there's any, it will rerun wget again, the problem is that this script will just keep looping, wget will download the same file continuously and just rename them if it already exists. How do I make wget re-run if there's any new URLs in the `wget-download-link.txt` file but stop it when the file already exists?

**@msturdy** I run your script but wget redownload and rename files that already exist, my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

test=/tmp/wget-download-link.txt
l=$(wc -l $test)

tail -n $l -f $test | while read url; do
    wget -o /tmp/wget.log -P /mnt/usb -i /tmp/wget-download-link.txt
done
```

my wget-download-link.txt file:

```
http://media2.giga.de/2014/11/angel-beats-kanade.jpg
http://juanestebanrojas.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/angel-beats-wallpapers-4.jpg
http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/30100000/Angel-Beats-new-life-angel-beats-30142329-2560-909.jpg
http://kristenhazelkannon.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/angelbeats2.jpg
```

Downloaded files:

```
angel-beats-wallpapers-4.jpg
angel-beats-wallpapers-4.jpg.1
Angel-Beats-new-life-angel-beats-30142329-2560-909.jpg.1
Angel-Beats-new-life-angel-beats-30142329-2560-909.jpg
angel-beats-kanade.jpg.2
angel-beats-kanade.jpg.1
angel-beats-kanade.jpg
angelbeats2.jpg
```

the script keeps running, and will just rename files to .1 .2 .3 etc.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED WITH THIS**

```
while [ true ] ; do
    urlfile=$( ls /root/wget/wget-download-link.txt | head -n 1 )
    dir=$( cat /root/wget/wget-dir.txt )
    if [ "$urlfile" = "" ] ; then
        sleep 180
        continue
    fi

    url=$( head -n 1 $urlfile )
    if [ "$url" = "" ] ; then
        mv $urlfile $urlfile.invalid
        continue
    fi

    mv $urlfile $urlfile.busy
    wget $url -P $dir -o /www/wget.log -c -t 100 -nc
    mv $urlfile.busy $urlfile.done
done
```